# Apache Flink - Access internal buffer of WindowedStream from another Stream's MapFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Apache Flink based streaming application with following setup:

- Data Source: generates data every minute.
- Windowed Stream using CountWindow with size=100, slide=1 (sliding count window).
- ProcessWindowFunction to apply some computation ( say F(x) ) on the data in the Window.
- Data sink to consume the output stream

This works fine. Now, I'd like to enable users to provide a function G(x) and apply it on the current data in the Window and send the output to the user in real-time

I am not asking about how to apply arbitrary function G(x) - I am using dynamic scripting to do that. I am asking how to access the buffered data in window from another stream's map function.

Some code to clarify

```
DataStream<Foo> in  = .... // source data produced every minute
    in
       .keyBy(new MyKeySelector())
       .countWindow(100, 1)
       .process(new MyProcessFunction())
       .addSink(new MySinkFunction())

// The part above is working fine. Note that windowed stream created by countWindow() function above has to maintain internal buffer. Now the new requirement

DataStream<Function> userRequest  = .... // request function from user

userRequest.map(new MapFunction<Function, FunctionResult>(){
   public FunctionResult map(Function Gx) throws Exception {
         Iterable<Foo> windowedDataFromAbove = // HOW TO GET THIS???
         FunctionResult result = Gx.apply(windowedDataFromAbove);
         return result;

   }
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the two streams, then use a [CoProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/co/CoProcessFunction.html). The method call that gets the stream of Functions can apply them to what's in the other method call's window.

If you want to broadcast Functions, then you'll either need to be using Flink 1.5 (which supports connecting keyed and broadcast streams), or use some helicopter stunts to create a single stream that can contain both Foo and Function types, with appropriate replication of Functions (and key generations) to simulate a broadcast.

Comment: That was my first thought. But API does not support connecting with WindowedStream https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/WindowedStream.html

Comment: In a (Co)ProcessFunction you can do your own windowing, by controlling when timers fire.

Comment: Implementing your own windowing will be much more efficient anyway -- with those sliding count windows each event is being copied into 100 window objects.

Comment: Is that really true? Why would Flink make 100 copies? Sliding count window can be implemented with fixed size buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Fx aggregates incoming foos on-fly and Gx processes a window's worth of foos, you should be able to achieve what you want as following:

```
DataStream<Function> userRequest  = .... // request function from user
Iterator<Function> iter = DataStreamUtils.collect(userRequest);
Function Gx = iter.next();

DataStream<Foo> in  = .... // source data
 .keyBy(new MyKeySelector())
 .countWindow(100, 1)
 .fold(new ArrayList<>(), new MyFoldFunc(), new MyProcessorFunc(Gx))
 .addSink(new MySinkFunction())
```

Fold function (operates on incoming data as soon as they arrive) can be defined like this:

```
private static class MyFoldFunc implements FoldFunction<foo, Tuple2<Integer, List<foo>>> {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<Integer, List<foo>> fold(Tuple2<Integer, List<foo>> acc, foo f) {
        acc.f0 = acc.f0 + 1; // if Fx is a simple aggregation (count)
        acc.f1.add(foo);
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Processor function can be something like this:

```
public class MyProcessorFunc
    extends ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<Integer, List<foo>>, Tuple2<Integer, FunctionResult>, String, TimeWindow> {

    public MyProcessorFunc(Function Gx) {
        super();
        this.Gx = Gx;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, Context context,
                        Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, List<foo>> accIt,
                        Collector<Tuple2<Integer, FunctionResult>> out) {
        Tuple2<Integer, List<foo> acc = accIt.iterator().next();
        out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, FunctionResult>(
            acc.f0, // your Fx aggregation
            Gx.apply(acc.f1), // your Gx results
        ));
    }
}
```

Please note that fold\reduce functions do not internally buffer elements by default. We use fold here to compute on-fly metrics and to also create a list of window items.

If you are interested in applying Gx on tumbling windows (not sliding), you could use tumbling windows in your pipeline. To compute sliding counts *too*, you could have another branch of your pipeline that computes sliding counts only (does not apply Gx). This way, you do not have to keep 100 lists per window.

Note: you may need to add the following dependency to use DataStreamUtils:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-contrib</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Gx is coming from end-users in its own DataStream. In your code sample above, Gx is declared as input parameter to MyProcessorFunc  constructor, but the caller code does not show how Gx is passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Sebastian Assuming you have function from user always available at the beginning of the program, you can convert it to iterator and provide it as input to MyProcessorFunc as illustrated by the updated answer. You can also collect 1st stream output (lists) in memory and wait until user request comes but this does not goes well with the way Flink works since you will block first stream computations (and keep its output in memory) until user request comes!

Comment: Function from User (Gx) is not available at the beginning of the program. It's sent via REST API by end users - which is converted to stream and sent to Flink for processing. However, there are built-in functions (Fx) that are being processed on windowed data. The question here how to utilize the windowed data that's already in memory (since it's being used to compute Fx), to compute Gx